# Newspapers or the newspapers?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

1a) The news is all over *the* newspapers around the world.

1b) The news is all over newspapers* around the world.

Why exactly do we use *the* even though it is not specifying some newspapers? I have seen the usage of *the* in some proper names such as *The* Golden Gate Bridge, what exactly is *the* conveying?

Comment: I'm not talking about "the news" part, read the question carefully, I'm talking solely about "newspapers".

Comment: My question is why did you use "the newspapers", why is it wrong to say " It's in all newspapers...". "The" newspapers sounds like some selected newspapers.

Comment: *The newspapers* almost always *is* used, so reasoning aside, it's become an idiom. People say *I read it in the news*, *I saw it on the news*, or *I read it in the newspapers*. Sometimes they'll say something different, but not normally. I can't say why common usage has made it be so.

Answer (score 2):

> 1a) The news is all over the newspapers around the world.
>
> 1b) The news is all over newspapers* around the world.
>
> Why exactly do we use the even though it is not specifying some newspapers?

"Newspapers" is the plural of "a newspaper". A/an noun = one example (from many) of a noun

"The newspapers" is the plural of "the newspaper".

"The noun = that [noun] of which we are aware. (Historically, "the" is a demonstrative adjective from the same stem as "that/those".)

It is important to understand that, in order to be qualified by "the", a noun must be either (a) described - "the traffic *in the town* or already known "The *moon* has risen."

> 1a) The news is all over the newspapers around the world.

The news is all over those newspapers (and we all are aware that there are newspapers) around the world.

> 1b) The news is all over newspapers* around the world.

The news is all over all examples of newspapers around the world.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it cuz I still would be aware that there are "newspapers" around the world without adding "the", and how exactly is "all examples of newspapers" different from your 1a? My guess is that by "the newspapers"  the speaker is referring to the newspaper of that specific day rather than any specific newspaper printing company?

Answer (score 1):

**the newspapers** (phrase)

From [MacMillian Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/the-newspapers) (American English defintion and example sentence):

> **the various newspapers that are published in a particular country or area**
>
> *You shouldn’t believe everything you read in the newspapers.*

I found this entry by chance. It never occurred to me that the phrase itself might be listed in a dictionary. I searched but did not find it in any others.

So the phrase *the newspapers* has its own meaning and refers to something specific, though not in the same sense as the two words would, of course (e.g., "the newspapers on the table").